# How to use jquery.validate plugin in cakephp form

Tags: jquery, cakephp, jquery-validate

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $('#StudentRegisterForm').validate({          
    rules: {
      email: {
        required:true,
        email:true
      }
    }
  });    
});
```

and in my form email:

```
<td><?php echo $form->input('email',array('class required email')); ?></td>
```

The problem is jquery validate plugin works on the input fields attribute 'name' but cakephp names it as `data[Student][email]`.  If I use this name in jquery its throwing an error.  If I rename the field in cakephp the email value is not passed to the database.  Is there any other round about way?

Comment: Just a minor typo in your example. You want class as an array. `'class'=>array('required','email')` for correctness ;)

Comment: for me its not working but this works 
 <?php echo $form->input('email',array('class'=>'required email')); ?>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need just need a minor tweak, set the rule using a string, like this:

```
$(function(){ //short for $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#RegisterForm').validate({
    rules: {
        "data[Student][email]": {
            required:true,
            email:true
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work, but I didn't think to quote the name! +1

Comment: @chinni776 - Welcome :) Be sure to accept answers via the checkmark so the next user finding this on google finds a working answer quickly :)

Comment: @chinni776 - Delay is never a problem...we just want the answers here to be as useful as possible to both the asker *and* the next person with this problem...googling for an answer and arriving here :)

Comment: Oh my Gosh...I can't explain how frustrating this problem was for me...except I was having it in Rails. Then some angel responded to my question by pointing me to this answer. THANK God. I LOVE SO!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem yesterday. The answer is to 'force' the name on the input field, like:

```
echo $form->input('cheque_number',array('name'=>'InvoiceChequeNumber','value'=>''));
```

I spent a while trying to avoid doing that, but I couldn't find any alternative. There are no problems for CakePHP when you do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is better to use, because this will maintain cake `this->data structure`, but second one is not. This is to remind that, when you will use the `data[modelname][fieldname]` give the class name in the input aray like:

```
<?php echo $form->input('email',array('type'=>'text','class' => array('required','email'),'error'=>false,'label'=>false,'div'=>false));  ?>
```