# How do I do client-side form validation in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use this plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Where #user_new is the id for my form, this is what my code looks like:

```
$('#user_new').validate({
    rules: {
        user[username]: "required",
        user[email]: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        user[username]: "Please specify your name",
        user[email]: {
            required: "We need your email address to contact you",
            email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
        }
    }
})
```

Where these are how my input fields look when the page is rendered (generated by Rails):

```
<input class="clearField curved" id="user_f_name" name="user[f_name]" size="30" type="text" value="First Name" /><br /> 
        <input class="clearField curved" id="user_l_name" name="user[l_name]" size="30" type="text" value="Last Name" /><br /> 
        <input class="clearField curved" id="user_username" name="user[username]" size="30" type="text" value="Username" /><br /> 
        <input class="clearField curved" id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" value="Password" /><br /> 
        <input class="clearField curved" id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="30" type="password" value="Password" /><br /> 
        <input class="clearField curved" id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" value="Email Address" /><br />
```

I was just trying to validate username & email first. Then take it from there.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to specify the syntax and the rules for working with this plugin.

Help!

Edit1: Here is the HTML output for the form tag:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/login" class="user_new" id="user_new" method="post">
```

As for the question about debug, when I include it like so:

```
$('#user_new').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        user_username: "required",
        user_email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        user_username: "Please specify your name",
        user_email: {
            required: "We need your email address to contact you",
            email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
        }
    }
});
```

I see nothing in my JS console.

Edit2: When I clear my login fields of data and press submit, it won't submit. Not sure if this is something to do with the validate() function actually working. But I see no messages pop-up or anything like that.

Edit3: It seems that the problem might be a disconnect between the ID & name fields being named differently. However, Rails assigns the name and ID to both fields - so not sure how to fix this.

Edit4: I found a solution. I added it to a comment under the chosen answer.

Comment: @littlechad put what inside the validate method instead?

Comment: comments on edit: try adding a container right after your input tag, i mean add this inside the validate method: errorPlacement: function(error, element){error.appendTo(element.next());}

Comment: btw where do I put that `errorPlacement` code ? Should it be after the second `}` after messages ? or should I take out the rules altogether and then add it ?

Comment: put it inside: $('#user_new').validate({ }); after the rules, and i updated my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think its because the value of the "name" attribute in the form (the input tag) does not match the jquery validate option

```
$('#user_new').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        user_username: "required", // should be: "user[username]"
        user_email: { // should be: "user[email]"
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        user_username: "Please specify your name", // should be: "user[username]"
        user_email: { // should be: "user[email]"
            required: "We need your email address to contact you",
            email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
        }
    }
});
```

Edit: take a look at this question, i think he has the same problem as you are [jquery.validate in cakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289000/how-to-use-jquery-validate-plugin-in-cakephp-form)

Edit2: to edit the way it display, put a container right after your input tag, let say

```
<div id="username_error"></div>//for username error message
```

add this codes:

```
$('#user_new').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        //rules
    },
    messages: {
        //messages
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if ( element.is(":radio") )
            error.appendTo( element.parent().next());//if its a radio button
        else if ( element.is(":checkbox") )
            error.appendTo ( element.next() );//if its a radio button
        else
            error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
    },//these lines of codes basically telling the jquery.validate plug-in to look for an element after
});
```

and then apply some css to tidy things up

```
<style>
#username_error{
   //a little something something
}
</style>
```

or you can always check the [documentation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for further modifications

Comment: Tried this...but still no luck. See the last edit on my question to see the updated code :|

Comment: The problem with this is that when I have user[username] I get an error in the JS console saying 'unexpected token ['

Comment: Dude...THANK YOU SO MUCH. That answer to that question was exactly it. So for those interested...the correct answer should be to put quotes around field names. In my case, make sure to use the value generated by Rails as the 'name'. So the correct code would look like: `rules {"user[username]" : "required", "user[email]" : { required: true, email true } }` WOW...I am SOOO glad I found this solution. This has been bugging me. I can't thank you enough. If you want to edit your answer to include this modification, I think the next frustrated person will thank you :)

Comment: Now...by any chance, do you have any resources on how to edit the way it is displayed because the error messages are looking weird. Should I do something like this `<input id="blah" name="blah" type="text" /><div id="error_messages"></div>` ?

Comment: I tried the error message placement and it hasn't worked out for me. Can you check out my code and see if you find anything wrong please: https://gist.github.com/770709   The top is the jQuery, the bottom is the Rails, and right below that is the HTML output from the Rails. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#user_new').validate({
    rules: {
        user_l_name: "required",
        user_email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        user_l_name: "Please specify your name",
        user_email: {
            required: "We need your email address to contact you",
            email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
        }
    }
})
```

Please make sure that the variables that you use in rules and Massage are the same as your input Id's and Name. What I'm trying to say is that your input Id and Name must be same for this to work.

I had the same problem, if this doesn't work, let me know so I can assist further.

Happy coding!!!!

Comment: So is there no way to get it to work without my name & id values being exact? Rails has a funny way of handling forms...so it automatically creates te id & name fields for me. My rails form field code looks like this: `<%= f.text_field :f_name, :value => "First Name", :class => "clearField curved" %><br />` which produces: `<input class="clearField curved" id="user_f_name" name="user[f_name]" size="30" type="text" value="First Name" /><br /> ` Any thoughts on how I can change this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this site http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation.  they have couple of example regarding JQuery validation.

Hope It helps...

Happy Coding!!!